# How can I list blobs in Azure's blob storage w/o recursively fetching all blobs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage

For Reference Here's Some Applicable Code:

```
const service = storage.createBlobService(connectionString);
service.listBlobsSegemented(containerName, null, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error();
  }
  data.entries.forEach(blob => {
    console.log('blob', blob)
  })
})
```

The problem is that `data.entries` includes EVERY SINGLE blob in the container. My container's structure looks something like this:

- file-1.csv
- file-2.csv
- archive/file-1-12341234123412.csv
- archive/file-2-12341234123412.csv

I can easily only fetch things within /archive with `listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix` such as:

```
service.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix(containerName, 'archive', null, 
  (err, data) => {
    ...
  }
)
```

However, I don't see a way to ONLY get the blobs at the root level.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was at a loss so I just randomly tried setting the delimiter to '/' and it worked. Too bad the documentation doesn't *quite* describe it's use as such...

Solution:

```
service.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, null, {delmiter: '/'}, (e, d) => {
  ....
})
```